# Shared Preferences

Tags: android

I want to show an edit box in shared preferences which should be read only for user but i should be able to change it at through code. how to achieve this?

Comment: you mean a TevtView ? Use setText()

Comment: but i dont want it to be editable by user. for the user value should be readonly

Comment: PLease go through it :http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.in/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html

Answer (score 3):

This [tutorial](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences) is good for creating preferences.
Also, if you want to change the preferences outside the `PreferenceActivity` you should use the Editor
For example:

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
e.putString("yourPreference", "default value");
e.commit();
```

I hope it helps

Also, as the documentation show in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), the `PreferenceActivity` is used for showing a visual style of the preferences. Also, as it is indicated in the same link, "the preferences will automatically save to `SharedPreferences` as the user interacts with them".

So, knowing this, if you don't want the user to edit that preference, you can use a `TextView`, or an `EditText` non/editable in the `PreferenceActivity`, and then use the code above to modify it outside the `PreferenceActivity`.
I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the info..i m using the same for storing shared perference,but I m using a text view and even user can edit that, which i dont want. how to do this?

Comment: you can create your custom Preference, which just the `Preference` with the text, or a `Preference` that you click and then a `Dialog` appears with the text you want. These are just examples, I dont know exactly what you are doing, since you didn't post your code. But these are some ideas that you can use to implement it. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a TextView. An EditText is a TextView subclass that's editable by the user by default. So you set the TextView, the user can't modify it and you set the text with

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the standard `PreferenceActivity`? If so, you should be able to go to your preference XML file, and set `android:enabled="false"`  on the ones you want to be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

i hope u should first display the value from shared pref and  use `android:editable="false"` in the textbox layout. this code will not allow the user to modify the text in editbox.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could display non editable text is to use a standard Preference and set it's summary (small text displayed under the Preference title).

```
<Preference
    android:key="text_preference"
    android:selectable="false"
    android:title="Title" />
```

.

```
    Preference textPreference = (Preference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("text_preference");
    textPreference.setSummary("Text");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this in the XML:
android:selectable="false"